# Spring data MongoDB org.springframework.data.auditing.config.AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.getAuditingHandlerBeanName

Tags: spring, mongodb

I can't solve this exception, it's my first app whith spring boot & spring data MongoDB.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.auditing.config.AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.getAuditingHandlerBeanName()Ljava/lang/String;
>       at org.springframework.data.auditing.config.AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerAuditHandlerBeanDefinition(AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.data.auditing.config.AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AuditingBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:62)
>       at org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.MongoAuditingRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(MongoAuditingRegistrar.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:151)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoAuditingHandler': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#51c6a38f' of type [org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'auditorAware'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#51c6a38f': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e7eb4f6' of type [org.springframework.aop.target.LazyInitTargetSource] while setting bean property 'targetSource';

Comment: it's simple i have just forget an @EnableAutoConfiguration